# How to escape from ClassCastException

Tags: java

This is my collection:

```
 db.power.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("513e4022cc6d8d7ff2c83239"),
        "Indicator" : "One",
        "sex" : "male"
}
```

How to escape from `ClassCastException`?

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;    
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;

public class Test {    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
        DB db = mongo.getDB("at");
        DBCollection testdata = db.getCollection("power");

        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("Indicator", "One");

        PowerData data = (PowerData) testdata.findOne(query);

        System.out.println(data.getSize());
    }    
}

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;    

public class PowerData extends BasicDBObject{       

    public String getSize() {
        return (String) get("sex");
    }

    public void setSize(String sex) {
        put("sex", sex);
    }       

    public String getIndicator() {
        return (String) get("Indicator");
    }

    public void setIndicator(String Indicator) {
        put("Indicator", Indicator);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return (String) get("_id");
    }

    public void setId(String _id) {
        put("_id", _id);
    }
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to PowerData
        at Test.main(Test.java:19)

Comment: You are trying to cast BasicDBObject to an object that extends BasicDBObject. This is not valid as BasicDBObject is not a PowerData object (where if you were trying to cast an instantiated PowerData to BasicDBObject that would be fine). You could instead instantiate and pass a PowerData object in to findOne() rather than a BasicDBObject.

Comment: Thanks , i passed the PowerData object in to findOne() , but still i get the same ClassCastExcetion .

Comment: this is a Java issue not a mongoDB issue, btw.  You probably want to fix the tags on the question.

Answer (score -1):

You could change your `PowerData` class like this:

```
public class PowerData extends BasicDBObject{

  private BasicDBObject wrapped;

  public PowerData(BasicDBObject o) {
    this.wrapped = o;
  }

  public String getSize() {
    return (String) o.get("sex");
  }

  public void setSize(String sex) {
    o.put("sex", sex);
  }

  public String getIndicator() {
    return (String) o.get("Indicator");
  }

  public void setIndicator(String Indicator) {
    o.put("Indicator", Indicator);
  }

  public String getId() {
    return (String) o.get("_id");
  }

  public void setId(String _id) {
    o.put("_id", _id);
  }
}
```

And in your `main` method, replace `PowerData data = (PowerData) testdata.findOne(query);` with following:

```
PowerData data = new PowerData(testdata.findOne(query));
```